Is the Web server on repo.skype.com down?
Since at least three days (today is 2024-06-01), repo.skype.com has been useless though up:
# cat /etc/apt/sources.list.d/skype-stable.list
deb [arch=amd64] https://repo.skype.com/deb stable main
# aptitude update
Hit http://security.debian.org/debian-security oldoldstable/updates InRelease
Hit http://debian.mirror.lrz.de/debian oldoldstable InRelease                                                                                             
Hit http://debian.mirror.lrz.de/debian oldoldstable-updates InRelease
Hit http://debian.mirror.lrz.de/debian oldstable InRelease
Hit http://security.debian.org/debian-security oldstable-security InRelease
Hit http://security.debian.org/debian-security stable-security InRelease
Hit http://debian.mirror.lrz.de/debian oldstable-updates InRelease                                                                                        
Hit http://debian.mirror.lrz.de/debian stable InRelease                                                                                                   
Hit http://debian.mirror.lrz.de/debian stable-updates InRelease                                                 
Ign https://repo.vivaldi.com/stable/deb stable InRelease
Hit https://repo.vivaldi.com/stable/deb stable Release              
Hit https://updates.signal.org/desktop/apt xenial InRelease          
Get: 1 https://packages.microsoft.com/ubuntu/22.04/mssql-server-2022 jammy InRelease [3,624 B]
Hit https://packages.microsoft.com/ubuntu/22.04/prod jammy InRelease
Get: 2 https://packages.microsoft.com/repos/code stable InRelease [3,590 B]
Ign https://repo.skype.com/deb stable InRelease                                                                                                           
Ign https://repo.skype.com/deb stable InRelease
Ign https://repo.skype.com/deb stable InRelease
Err https://repo.skype.com/deb stable InRelease
  504  Gateway Time-out [IP: 2a02:26f0:12d:5ac::1263 443]
Fetched 7,214 B in 1min 48s (66 B/s)
W: Failed to fetch https://repo.skype.com/deb/dists/stable/InRelease: 504  Gateway Time-out [IP: 2a02:26f0:12d:5ac::1263 443]
W: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
                                         
# ping4 repo.skype.com
PING  (104.108.144.148) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from a104-108-144-148.deploy.static.akamaitechnologies.com (104.108.144.148): icmp_seq=1 ttl=54 time=22.4 ms
64 bytes from a104-108-144-148.deploy.static.akamaitechnologies.com (104.108.144.148): icmp_seq=2 ttl=54 time=22.6 ms
64 bytes from a104-108-144-148.deploy.static.akamaitechnologies.com (104.108.144.148): icmp_seq=3 ttl=54 time=22.7 ms
64 bytes from a104-108-144-148.deploy.static.akamaitechnologies.com (104.108.144.148): icmp_seq=4 ttl=54 time=22.4 ms
^C
---  ping statistics ---
4 packets transmitted, 4 received, 0% packet loss, time 3004ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 22.361/22.520/22.684/0.132 ms
# ping6 repo.skype.com
PING repo.skype.com(g2a02-26f0-012d-05aa-0000-0000-0000-1263.deploy.static.akamaitechnologies.com (2a02:26f0:12d:5aa::1263)) 56 data bytes
64 bytes from g2a02-26f0-012d-05aa-0000-0000-0000-1263.deploy.static.akamaitechnologies.com (2a02:26f0:12d:5aa::1263): icmp_seq=1 ttl=59 time=22.0 ms
64 bytes from g2a02-26f0-012d-05aa-0000-0000-0000-1263.deploy.static.akamaitechnologies.com (2a02:26f0:12d:5aa::1263): icmp_seq=2 ttl=59 time=22.4 ms
64 bytes from g2a02-26f0-012d-05aa-0000-0000-0000-1263.deploy.static.akamaitechnologies.com (2a02:26f0:12d:5aa::1263): icmp_seq=3 ttl=59 time=22.6 ms
64 bytes from g2a02-26f0-012d-05aa-0000-0000-0000-1263.deploy.static.akamaitechnologies.com (2a02:26f0:12d:5aa::1263): icmp_seq=4 ttl=59 time=22.4 ms
^C
--- repo.skype.com ping statistics ---
4 packets transmitted, 4 received, 0% packet loss, time 3005ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 22.049/22.364/22.628/0.206 ms

Why (has Skype or its Debian repository been discontinued?), who is the culprit, and what to do?

I’m voting to close this question because this about some website status and nothing to do with Linux or UNIX

Microsoft has discontinued the support for Skype DEB and RPM packages and switched to Snap.
See this update from Microsoft for more details.

Yes. I cannot hit this site directly and uptimerobot reports the same. 
Also, just a note. This site is CDN hosted by Akamai. Pinging the server only proves that Akamai's content endpoint is available. These endpoints are shared by multiple customers.
This same type of event happened exactly 4 years ago, so it might be a contract expiration or something as simple as an invalid SSL/HTTPS certificate which didn't get renewed and applied.

Akamai SSL verification https://community.akamai.com/customers/s/article/Origin-SSL-Verification-Process?language=en_US
